# protractor async await not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

Hello i'm trying to use async await but not sure exactly how to do it. Here is my my code. I do have node 7.6.0 installed. protractor v5.1.1 and promise manager disabled in my conf.js.

```
"use strict";

console.log('111');

describe('A', function(){
    console.log('222');

    it('B', async function(){

        await browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com');
        console.log('333');

    });

});
```

when I run the test, it says my it callback is not a function.

```
1) A encountered a declaration exception
  - Error: async function (){

        browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com');
        console.log('333');

    } is not a function

        browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com');
        console.log('333');

    } is not a function
```

why? and how do I fix it? Not sure if I'm writing it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: i put the async function inside the it block and called it from inside the block as well.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same issue with nodejs 7.9 + protractor 5.1.1

This is an issue in jasminewd2, and still open, see the following link for more detail:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4186

In the wiki page of the issue above, there is a pull request https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/pull/87 which has been merged to jasminewd several days ago, I manually modify the file `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js` according to the pull request and works fine.